# How does Python provide a maintainable way to pass data structures around in a system?

Tags: python

I am new to dynamic languages in general, and I have discovered that languages like Python prefer simple data structures, like dictionaries, for sending data between parts of a system (across functions, modules, etc).

In the C# world, when two parts of a system communicate, the developer defines a class (possibly one that implements an interface) that contains properties (like a Person class with a Name, Birth date, etc) where the sender in the system instantiates the class and assigns values to the properties.  The receiver then accesses these properties.  The class is called a DTO and it is "well- defined" and **explicit**.  If I remove a property from the DTO's class, the compiler will instantly warn me of all parts of the code that use that DTO and are attempting to access what is now a non-existent property.  I know exactly what has broken in my codebase.

In Python, functions that produce data (senders) create **implicit** DTOs by building up dictionaries and returning them.  Coming from a compiled world, this scares me.  I immediately think of the scenario of a large code base where a function producing a dictionary has the name of a key changed (or a key is removed altogether) and boom- tons of potential KeyErrors begin to crop up as pieces of the code base that work with that dictionary and expect a key are no longer able to access the data they were expecting.  Without unit testing, the developer would have no reliable way of knowing where these errors will appear.

Maybe I misunderstand altogether.  Are dictionaries a best practice tool for passing data around?  If so, how do developers solve this kind of problem?  How are implicit data structures and the functions that use them maintained?  How do I become less afraid of what seems like a huge amount of uncertainty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Coming from a compiled world, this scares me. I immediately think of
>   the scenario of a large code base where a function producing a
>   dictionary has the name of a key changed (or a key is removed
>   altogether) and boom- tons of potential KeyErrors begin to crop up as
>   pieces of the code base that work with that dictionary and expect a
>   key are no longer able to access the data they were expecting.

I would just like to highlight this part of your question, because I feel this is the main point you are trying to understand.

Python's development philosophy is a bit different; as objects can mutate without throwing errors (for example, you can add properties to instances without having them declared in the class) a common programming practice in Python is [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html):

> EAFP
>
> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many try and except
>   statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many
>   other languages such as C.

The LBYL referred to from the quote above is "Look Before You Leap":

> LBYL
>
> Look before you leap. This coding style explicitly tests for
>   pre-conditions before making calls or lookups. This style contrasts
>   with the EAFP approach and is characterized by the presence of many if
>   statements.
>
> In a multi-threaded environment, the LBYL approach can risk
>   introducing a race condition between “the looking” and “the leaping”.
>   For example, the code, if key in mapping: return mapping[key] can fail
>   if another thread removes key from mapping after the test, but before
>   the lookup. This issue can be solved with locks or by using the EAFP
>   approach.

So I would say this is a bit of the norm and in Python you *expect* the objects will behave well and handle themselves with grace (mainly by throwing up lots of exceptions). Traditional "object hiding" and "interface contracts" are not what Python is all about. It is just like learning anything else, you have to acclimate to the programming environment and its rules.

The other part of your question:

> Are dictionaries a best practice tool for passing data around? If so,
>   how do developers solve this kind of problem?

The answer here is *depends on your problem domain*. If your problem domain does not lend itself to custom objects, then you can pass around any kind of container (lists, tuples, dictionaries) around.  If however all you have to pass around decorated data ("rich" data) is objects, then your code becomes littered with classes that don't define behavior but rather properties of things.

Oh, by the way - this getting of keys and raising `KeyError` problem is already solved, as Python dictionaries have a `get` method, which can return a default value (it returns the sentinel `None` object by default) when a key doesn't exist:

```
>>> d = {'a': 'b'}
>>> d['b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'b'
>>> d.get('b')  # None is returned, which is the only
                # object that is not printed by the
                # Python interactive interpreter.
>>> d.get('b','default')
'default'
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is genuinely extremely helpful.  The question that comes to mind now though is how boolean expressions, assignments, etc. would work with None- but I'm sure that getting "comfortable" with a None return value is the kind of thing that comes with experience.

Answer (score 2):

When using Python for a large project using automated testing is a must because otherwise you would never dare to do any serious refactoring and the code base will rot in no time as all your changes will always try to touch nothing leading to bad solution (simply because you'd be too scared to implement the correct solution instead).

Indeed the above is true even with C++ or, as it often happens with large projects, with mixed-languages solutions.

Not longer than a few HOURS ago for example I had to make a branch for a four line bugfix (one of the lines is a single brace) for a specific customer because the trunk evolved too much from the version he has in production and the guy in charge of the release process told me his use cases have not yet been covered with manual testing in current version and therefore I cannot upgrade his installation.

The compiler can tell you something, but it cannot provide any confidence in stability after a refactoring if the software is complex. The idea that if some piece of code compiles then it's correct is bogus (possibly with the exception of hello_world.cpp).

That said you normally don't use dictionaries in Python for everything, unless you really care about the dynamic aspect (but in this case the code doesn't access the dictionary with a literal key). If your Python code has a lot of `d["foo"]` instead of `d[k]` when using dicts then I'd say there is a smell of a design problem.

Comment: _"The idea that if some piece of code compiles then it's correct is bogus (possibly except in hello_world.cpp)."_ - if I could, I would give you +10 just for this; alas you can have my lowly +1.

Comment: From what little I have written, a good amount of it _does_ have `d["foo"]` like you mention.  If I simply want to pass a simple data structure as a container for a few strings, for example, from one module to another, what would be a decent way to do it? And in the `d[k]` example, where does `k` come from?  Function argument? Global?

Comment: @SanjeevMundluru: If it's a generic container for strings then the code shouldn't expect to find or not a specific key and therefore will not break if you remove one specific string. If it's instead a container where keys `name`, `email` and `phone` must and are always present then the object is a class instance and not a container for strings (and you can still write also generic code that works on all the fields of the class using `obj.__dict__`).

Comment: Perfect- that's exactly what I was looking for.  So dictionaries are more general purpose.  You may use them to iterate over the keys for example and access each value through a loop variable as the `k` in `d[k]` but if you want to impose consistent content or structure in your data that dictates what should or should not exist, you use a class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think passing dictionaries is the only way to pass structured data across parts of a  system. I've seen lots of people use classes for that. Actually [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is a good fit for that as well.

> Without unit testing, the developer would have no reliable way of
>   knowing where these errors will appear

Now why would you not write unit tests?

In Python you don't rely on a compiler to catch your errors. If you really need static checking of your code, you can use one of several static analysis tools out there (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python))

Comment: The argument I always hear for classes vs dictionaries is that classes will usually have functions that are associated with the attributes of the class.  I will look into namedtuple.  
As far as unit testing goes, it's not about refusal to do it, just that devs can tend to become lazy.  What I'm really looking for is a sense of confidence or "comfort" with this way of working. pylint may be the answer.